# How to send json data from android app to website

Tags: javascript, json, web, kotlin

I'm trying to send an Android edittext in JSON form to display the data on a website in webview in the app. This has to work simultaneously as the user clicks a button in the app. I've looked all around stackoverflow and youtube but haven't found a way to do so. The part I'm having trouble is how to send the data to url and how to retrieve it using javascript. I would just like guidance on what to use and how to do so. The person that gave me this work said that I don't need access to a server. Thank you!

For reference:

This is mainactivity from app:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)    
        button.setOnClickListener() {
            val inputValue: String? = input_area.text.toString()
            if (inputValue == null || inputValue.trim() == "") {
                //if (inputValue.trim() == "") {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please input data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else {
                val toSend= JSONObject()
                toSend.put("input", inputValue)
            }
        }
    }
    private inner class Callback : WebViewClient() {  

        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            return false
        }

    }
}
```

This is my html for where I need to receive the data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.input;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use websockets to make the communication real time.

From what I understood you want the data to be shown on the website as soon as it is sent from the android application.

To achieve that use a solution like Firebase that allows you to setup real time databases and make updates in real time.

Go on that link to see how it is done on android https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

And here https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup to check how it is done on the web